# When creating an electron wrapper what is the right way to watch for notifications?

Tags: notifications, electron, trello, google-inbox

I am working with electron and various websites such as trello and inbox. I would like to add native notifications (which functionally i have working) however i need to know what the correct approach is to watch the site for notifications.

Do I ask the user to authenticate twice (once to login and again for the api if the site has one) or do i need to find something in the window object to watch?

Plenty of electron apps seem to be able to do this but i've had no luck hunting through github repos.

Any help or direction would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> i need to know what the correct approach is to watch the site for notifications.

Check out [trello webhooks](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/webhook)